# .net: Converting a Generic List to a DataReader?

Tags: .net, winforms, sqldatareader, sqlbulkcopy, generic-list

Hi
I have a Populated Generic List in a winform and now wanna to send its data into a SQL server table as a bulk Copy. As I read the SqlBulkCopy Class, it needs a data reader as a source.

Now, how can I convert it to a DataReader?

Thank you

Comment: See this answer for converting a generic list to a DataTable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/generic-list-to-datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to DataTable and send to SqlBulkCopy. It would be much easier, and there is no performance penalty, because all data is already present in memory.

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258310/get-an-idatareader-from-a-typed-list) on SO.

Answer (score 3):

If the data-volume is sane enough to exist as a `List<T>`, you might as well just construct a `DataTable` and push the data in that way. I don't *like* `DataTable`, but it does this job nicely. The alternative would be to write a custom `IDataReader` implementation [like this](https://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/b1d70b504cdee2ad?hl=en), but which iterates over the items in the list each time. I'm not sure it is worth the effort.