# Is it better to pass large inserts to SQL Server as a table valued parameter, or as a string insert statement?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing a .NET application that writes data to SQL Server 2008r2.  I have two options for inserting the data, either I can create a large string insert statement, and send it as a text command, or I can collect the data in a .NET DataTable, and pass it as a table valued parameter.  What are the benefits and costs of each method?

(I am omitting a good deal of code since I am just asking about the relative benefits, not the specific syntax)

e.g.:

Option 1:

```
    string insert = @"insert into MyTable (id, val) values
        ( 1, 'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d');"
```

Option 2:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(string));
    ....
    create procedure uspMyProc 
                    @tt ttMyTableType readonly
                as
                begin
                    insert into TestTable1 (id, strValue)
                    select myId, myVal from @tt;
                end"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Option #3. Use SqlCommand. The structure can be dynamic (*if and only if needed*), while keeping the data parametrized.

Comment: (Many SqlCommand inserts are is plenty fast when transactions are used correctly.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 3:** In the first instance I would populate the insert stored procedure with one insert statement's worth of parameters and call it multiple times in a loop from the C# code:

**Option 4:** If you truly have ***lots*** of rows to insert, perhaps you need to look into the [SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). It consumes either `DataTable`, `DataRow` or an `IDataReader`. You can make an `IDataReader` from a list of objects using some custom code, a question of this ilk is asked here:

[Get an IDataReader from a typed List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258310/get-an-idatareader-from-a-typed-list)

---

I would say it depends.

If you really want to pass many rows of parameters in tabular form, for whatever reason, use a table valued parameter - that's what it's there for.

I have seen Option 1 - some generic DAL code would script out a SQL "batch" of commands to run. It worked, but didn't give any defence against injection attacks. Parameterised SQL does.

---

All that said, I would favour calling the insert sproc once for each row to be inserted from code - the calls will be fully parameterised and performance is fine. If performance becomes a problem I would favour Option 4.

Comment: also helps defend against SQL Injection

Comment: Thank you.  I was not aware of the SqlBulkCopy class.  I think that is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

How big is big? If it is huge, nothing beats SqlBulkCopy. I've actually found TVP performance disappointing. For query plan re-use, I'm a fan of parameterised and massively-reused statements. Dapper can help with this, allowing you to pass a list of objects to a query - it will then add in the named parameters per object by member name, at many thousands of operations per second. For example:

```
conn.Execute(
    "insert foo (Id,Name) values (@Id,@Name)",
    listOfObjects);
```

This will iterate the list and use `.Id` and `.Name` from each object in turn to execute the query.

Comment: Please provide a link to Drapper

Comment: @Blam either type "dapper" into nuget, or: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ (it is the custom stack we use for high-perf data access here at stackoverflow)

Answer (score 4):

Values is limited to 1000

And values appears to have some performance issues

[Insert Performance Issues With Multiple Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635818/multiple-insert-statements-vs-single-insert-with-multiple-values)

I use TVP for inserting thousand of rows and it works great for me.  I use a List collection as the TVP source as DataTable has more overhead.   Insert the rows sorted by the PK if you can.

With that said I am going to try out the answer from Marc Gravell.

JNK has a general distrust of TVP.

Comment: are you sure about `DataTable` and overhead vs Enumerable type and each record with a round trip  from c# to sqlserver on every record? (i reached this question only cause i resarch this issue) for my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365407/c-sharp-sql-server-best-way-to-delete-multiple-rows-in-one-go-using-a-stor#34366719] in which i try to use it for mutiple deletes by record id.

Comment: _"The data is structured as a strongly-typed set of rows on the client, and winds up as a strongly-typed set of rows on the server in a single round-trip"_  from -  https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/

Comment: @Robb_2015 Are you sure you read my answer?  Values clearly addresses Option 1:.  As for Option2 I state it (TVP) works great.  No where in my answer do I assert a TVP is not stronly typed nor that is results in multiple round trips.