# SQL Server : delete multiple rows with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete multiple rows from a SQL Server table, matching on multiple conditions.

Assume the following table:

[image: Table holding data to delete]

In my C# code, I have a list with objects containing the following values.
Assume this list to be of a decent size.

```
{Name = 'Bob', Address = '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC'},
{Name = 'Maria', Address = '21B Baker St, London, England.'}
```

What would be the cleanest way to delete these values? I would rather not run one query per record in my list.

Normally I would do something like this, but in this case, it will empty my entire table (which is not what I want).

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE Name IN ('Bob', 'Maria')
  AND Address IN ('1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC', '21B Baker St, London, England.')
```

This works, but it is not something I would consider 'clean' with a decently sized list

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE 
   (Name = 'Bob' AND Address = '1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC') OR
   (Name = 'Maria' AND Address = '21B Baker St, London, England.')
```

I'm using Dapper in my C# application, so both Dapper snippets and raw SQL could help me out.
As
a sucker for clean SQL, I'm really curious how clean this gets.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: One way to delete several rows using one delete query is by using `Table-Valued Parameters (TVP)`. Here is a sample https://stackoverflow.com/a/34366991/12833205 of using TVP to delete multiple rows. But why don't you want to delete rows using one query for each row? Another approach is to create a stored procedure that will accept TVP and delete rows in a for loop.

Comment: Have you tried inserting your list into a #temp table and then joining the #temp table onto your data table with appropriate join conditions to delete? The trick with Dapper and #temp tables is to ensure all operations are on the same connection - and that Dapper is not closing/reopening the connection between operations.

Comment: Where did you get the values to delete from? Presumably they came from the database in the first place, so why are you not deleting by primary key?

Comment: @TomC PK is based on two FK's, so the problem will remain the same. You could argue to always use singe PK instead of composite key. I guess both have their advantages/disadvantages

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Works like a charm. Not the cleanest, but certainly not too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to consider here. When you deploy another variant of a SQL string you're not only generating a new string (allocations in your application), but also query plans on the SQL server. Each permutation has its own plan and cache. This won't likely matter at small scale, but worth keeping in mind.

Often the cleanest way most things is the simplest. To do a small number of items, keeping it simple generally means a loop. Dapper accepts an `IEnumerable` in the parameters and when it finds an enumerable and it'll execute the same command with the different parameters `n` times. Though this is round-trips to the server and isn't great for *huge* numbers, it's very clean. Here's what it'd look like, assuming:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd delete multiple like this:

```cs
var toDelete = new List<Foo>() {
    new Foo { Name = "Bob", Address = "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC" },
    new Foo { Name = "Maria", Address = "21B Baker St, London, England." }
};

conn.Execute(@"Delete From MyTable Where Name = @Name And Address = @Address", toDelete);
```

Comment: I just tried this solution on PostgreSQL with dapper. It worked, indeed. But the problem I see is that Dapper executes each of these Foo objects in a separate call. With that, when I want to delete, let's say, 300 records, Dapper executes 300 queries against the database. It's a real waste of resources. So instead, I've tried just to compose a standard sql query as
`$"Delete From MyTable Where (Name, Address) in ({parameters})"`
and got way better speed

Answer (score 0):

For SQL

```
DECLARE @JsonUserDetails VARCHAR(MAX) = '[
{"strName":"Bob","strAddress":"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC"},
{"strName":"Maria","strAddress":"21B Baker St, London, England."}]'

DELETE T1 FROM MyTable  T1
INNER JOIN 
OPENJSON(@JsonUserDetails) WITH (strName varchar(35),strAddress varchar(50)) AS TEMP ON T1.Name = TEMP.strName AND TEMP.strAddress = T1.Address
```

For Dapper Create the list of info to be deleted and serialize the list and pass that object to dapper method