# Need recommendations on pushing the envelope with SqlBulkCopy on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, scalability, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, database-performance

I am designing an application, one aspect of which is that it is supposed to be able to receive massive amounts of data into SQL database. I designed the database stricture as a single table with bigint identity, something like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
   _id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    field1, field2, ...
)
```

I will omit how am I intending to perform queries, since it is irrelevant to the question I have.

I have written a prototype, which inserts data into this table using SqlBulkCopy. It seemed to work very well in the lab. I was able to insert tens of millions records at a rate of ~3K records/sec (full record itself is rather large, ~4K). Since the only index on this table is autoincrementing bigint, I have not seen a slowdown even after significant amount of rows was pushed.

Considering that the lab SQL server was a virtual machine with relatively weak configuration (4Gb RAM, shared with other VMs disk sybsystem), I was expecting to get significantly better throughput on the physical machine, but it didn't happen, or lets say the performance increase was negligible. I could, maybe get 25% faster inserts on physical machine. Even after I configured 3-drive RAID0, which performed 3 times faster than a single drive (measured by a benchmarking software), I got no improvement. Basically: faster drive subsystem, dedicated physical CPU and double RAM almost didn't translate into any performance gain.

I then repeated the test using biggest instance on Azure (8 cores, 16Gb), and I got the same result. So, adding more cores did not change insert speed.

At this time I have played around with following software parameters without any significant performance gain:

- Modifying SqlBulkInsert.BatchSize parameter
- Inserting from multiple threads simultaneously, and adjusting # of threads
- Using table lock option on SqlBulkInsert
- Eliminating network latency by inserting from a local process using shared memory driver

I am trying to increase performance at least 2-3 times, and my original idea was that throwing more hardware would get tings done, but so far it doesn't.

So, can someone recommend me:

- What resource could be suspected a bottleneck here? How to confirm?
- Is there a methodology I could try to get reliably scalable bulk insert improvement considering there is a single SQL server system?

**UPDATE** I am certain that load app is not a problem. It creates record in a temporary queue in a separate thread, so when there is an insert it goes like this (simplified):

```
===>start logging time
int batchCount = (queue.Count - 1) / targetBatchSize + 1;
Enumerable.Range(0, batchCount).AsParallel().
    WithDegreeOfParallelism(MAX_DEGREE_OF_PARALLELISM).ForAll(i =>
{
    var batch = queue.Skip(i * targetBatchSize).Take(targetBatchSize);
    var data = MYRECORDTYPE.MakeDataTable(batch);
    var bcp = GetBulkCopy();
    bcp.WriteToServer(data);
});
====> end loging time
```

timings are logged, and the part that creates a queue never takes any significant chunk

**UPDATE2** I have implemented collecting how long each operation in that cycle takes and the layout is as follows:

- `queue.Skip().Take()` - negligible
- `MakeDataTable(batch)` - 10%
- `GetBulkCopy()` - negligible
- `WriteToServer(data)` - 90%

**UPDATE3** I am designing for standard version of SQL, so I cannot rely on partitioning, since it's only available in Enterprise version. But I tried a variant of partitioning scheme:

- created 16 filegroups (G0 to G15),
- made 16 tables for insertion only (T0 to T15) each bound to its individual group. Tables are with no indexes at all, not even clustered int identity.
- threads that insert data will cycle through all 16 tables each. This makes it almost a guarantee that each bulk insert operation uses its own table

That did yield ~20% improvement in bulk insert. CPU cores, LAN interface, Drive I/O were not maximized, and used at around 25% of max capacity.

**UPDATE4** I think it is now as good as it gets. I was able to push inserts to a reasonable speeds using following techniques:

- Each bulk insert goes into its own table, then results are merged into main one
- Tables are recreated fresh for every bulk insert, table locks are used
- Used IDataReader implementation [from here](http://spikes.codeplex.com/) instead of DataTable.
- Bulk inserts done from multiple clients
- Each client is accessing SQL using individual gigabit VLAN
- Side processes accessing the main table use NOLOCK option
- I examined sys.dm_os_wait_stats, and sys.dm_os_latch_stats to eliminate contentions

I have a hard time to decide at this point who gets a credit for answered question. Those of you who don't get an "answered", I apologize, it was a really tough decision, and I thank you all.

**UPDATE5**: Following item could use some optimization:

- Used IDataReader implementation [from here](http://spikes.codeplex.com/) instead of DataTable.

Unless you run your program on machine with massive CPU core count, it could use some re-factoring. Since it is using reflection to generate get/set methods, that becomes a major load on CPUs. If performance is a key, it adds a lot of performance when you code IDataReader manually, so that it is compiled, instead of using reflection

Comment: Perhaps the performance bottleneck is the application's ability to supply records to SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: What kind of resource utilizations are you seeing during this?  You cannot really do effective performance tuning without this kind of information.

Comment: And while we're at it, multithreading the insert might not help if the C# application is generating the rows. At some point the GC is going to run and reclaim memory, and (potentially) suspend threads to do this (depending on the version of the .NET Framework you're running, and whether it's the server/workstation GC).

Comment: @ta.speot.is & all: I have good reasons to believe that app used to insert dummy rows is not a problem (see update).

Comment: @galets Is that `Skip` operation `O(1)` or `O(n)`? And `MakeDataTable` sounds expensive. `WriteToServer` can take an `IDataReader`, you could implement a lightweight `IDataReader` wrapper over whatever you're sending to the server. Have you profiled the .NET app?

Comment: @ta.speot.is good point(s). I will see if changing that will be any difference.

Comment: @ta.speot.is UPDATE: I changed the Skip().Take() pattern to List.GetRange() with no observable improvement, so that's not it.

Comment: @galets [`GetRange` *creates a shallow copy of a range of elements in the source*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) so we're still talking `O(n)`.

Comment: You might want to run the evaluation version of http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ against your app and make sure it's not wasting its time prior to calling `WriteToServer`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I did run some more testing. Both GetRange() and Skip().Take() patterns are approximately equivalent in performance, and both take negligible amount of time out of cycle. MakeDataTable() does take ~10% of cycle time, and 90% is WriteToServer. Here's a typical breakdown: ticks_SkipTake 0, ticks_MakeDataTable 7,620,762, ticks_GetBulkCopy 80,008, ticks_
WriteToServer 76,737,673. So, although MakeDataTable could use some improvement, biggest offender is still bulk insert. By the way, how do you suggest implementing IDataReader? There's tons of methods to implement

Comment: @ta.speot.is I implemented IDataReader based on the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258310/get-an-idatareader-from-a-typed-list and achieved ~10% speed increase.

Comment: out of curiosity, whats the data type for field1, field2, etc... are they fixed length or variable length? whats the approx. size for each row?

Comment: @DK Variable. Around 150 fields, mixture of int, datetime, uniqueidentifier, and nvarchar(max). On average a record is ~4-5K

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For recommendations on tuning SQL Server for bulk loads, see the [Data Loading and Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) paper from MS, and also [Guidelines for Optimising Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445%28SQL.105%29.aspx) from books online. Although they focus on bulk loading from SQL Server, most of the advice applies to bulk loading using the client API. This papers apply to SQL 2008 - you don't say which SQL Server version you're targetting
Both have quite a lot of information which it's worth going through in detail. However, some highlights:

- Minimally log the bulk operation. Use bulk-logged or simple recovery.
  You may need to enable traceflag 610 (but see the caveats on doing
  this)
- Tune the batch size
- Consider partitioning the target table
- Consider dropping indexes during bulk load

Nicely summarised in this flow chart from [Data Loading and Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):
[image]

As others have said, you need to get some peformance counters to establish the source of the bottleneck, since your experiments suggest that IO might not be the limitation.
[Data Loading and Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) includes a list of SQL wait types and performance counters to monitor (there are no anchors in the document to link to but this is about 75% through the document, in the section "Optimizing Bulk Load")

*UPDATE*

It took me a while to find the link, but [this SQLBits talk](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event7/Designing_and_Tuning_high_speed_data_loading) by Thomas Kejser is also well worth watching - the [slides](http://sqlbits.com/Downloads/142/Designing%20and%20Tuning%20high%20speed%20data%20loading%20-%20Thomas%20Kejser.pptx) are available if you don't have time to watch the whole thing. It repeats some of the material linked here but also covers a couple of other suggestions for how to deal with high incidences of particular performance counters.

Comment: I will look through the links you posted, and i repped you for the effort. But I do have to note that I did put db into simple recovery mode (which is no log), tuned batch size(as I stated), regarding indexes and partitioning: there is only one index, and if you look at it, it should not affect insert speed. Since insert speed does not degrade with # of records, I do not think partitioning is necessary

Comment: @galets - added another link. Your autoincrementing PK may be limiting the speed as all the inserting threads may be contending for the hot page at the end of the table. If this is the case, consider "hash partitioning" as described in the Kejser SQLBits talk linked above. Also, do some testing to ensure you're getting minimal logging. Simple recovery mode is not unlogged; the transaction log will be written (and grow) for the duration of the transaction.

Comment: I tested the theory that _id could be a problem by completely dropping it and leaving the table without index completely. It seems not to be a problem, the speed stayed exactly as it was previously. I do thank you for the effort however, as well as for the links you submitted. They gave me some ideas that I'll be trying out

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have done a lot however I am not sure if you have had chance to study Alberto Ferrari [SqlBulkCopy Performance Analysis](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2009/11/30/sqlbulkcopy-performance-analysis.aspx) report, which describes several factors to consider the performance related with SqlBulkCopy. I would say lots of things discussed in that paper is still worth trying to that would good to try first.

Comment: thanks, great read, I got some good ideas from it. One thing I cannot achieve completely is 100% utilization of either CPU, or disk, or network, and it drives me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are not getting 100% utilization on CPU, IO or memory. But if you simply want to improve your bulk load speeds, here is something to consider:

1. Partition you data file into different files. Or if they are coming from different sources, then simply create different data files.
2. Then run multiple bulk inserts simultaneously.

Depending on your situation the above may not be feasible; but if you can then I am sure it should improve your load speeds.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I already tried it. Although it did work, the difference was not dramatic. See my UPDATE3 comment.