# How to assign default value for DBNull values from DataTable when performing bulk insert/update as IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Background**

I have developing a simple MVC 5 application which able to import Excel file to a SQL Server 2012 database with Entity Framework 6 and SqlBulkTools ([Github](https://github.com/gtaylor44/SqlBulkTools)). The code structure has shown below.

Model (Project.Models)

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public String SessionNo { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public String LotNumber { get; set; }
    public String RegNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal? InitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? FinalPrice { get; set; }
    public String TaxNote { get; set; }
}

public class FileModel
{
    public String FileName { get; set; } // Excel file name
    public String SheetName { get; set; } // source worksheet name
    public String TableName { get; set; } // target table name
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileToUpload { get; set; } // uploaded Excel file (version 2007 or above)
}
```

Controller (Project.Controllers.FileController)

```
using SqlBulkTools;

[Route("File")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    // class-level single datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    // GET
    public ViewResult Import()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(FileModel model)
    {
        // when file name is empty, execute these lines below
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FileName)
        {
            foreach (String file in Request.Files)
            {
                model.FileToUpload = this.Request.Files[file];
            }

            if (model.FileToUpload != null && model.FileToUpload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                model.FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileToUpload.FileName);
            }
        }

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Imported"), model.FileName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
        }
        model.FileToUpload.SaveAs(path);

        String oleconstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=2\"; Persist Security Info=False";
        String olecmdstring = "SELECT * FROM [" + model.SheetName + "$]";

        using (var oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            using (var olecon = new OleDbConnection(oleconstring))
            {
                try 
                {
                    oleda.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(olecmdstring, olecon);
                    oleda.Fill(dt);

                    // remove all "null" values from Excel worksheet if any
                    dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => !r.ItemArray.All(f => f is DBNull || f as String == null || String.Compare((f as String).Trim(), String.Empty) == 0)).CopyToDataTable();

                    // trim all whitespaces after column names
                    foreach (DataColumn cols in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        cols.ColumnName = cols.ColumnName.Trim();
                    }

                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        switch (model.TableName)
                        {
                            case "Product":
                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
                            {
                                if (dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"].ToString().Equals("None", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"] = DBNull.Value;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"] is DateTime)
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"] = String.Format("{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"]);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows[i]["TaxNote"] = DBNull.Value;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            var bulkOperation = new BulkOperations();

                            // convert DataTable into IEnumerable for bulk upsert
                            var productList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Product()
                            {
                                SessionNo = x.Field<double>("SessionNo").ToString(),
                                ProductName = x.Field<String>("ProductName"),
                                Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
                                LotNumber = x.Field<String>("LotNumber"),
                                RegNumber = x.Field<String>("RegNumber"),

                                // this won't work if source column in Excel contains null
                                InitPrice = (decimal)(x.Field<Nullable<double>>("InitPrice") != null ? x.Field<Nullable<double>>("InitPrice") : 0),

                                // this won't work if source column in Excel contains null
                                FinalPrice = (decimal)(x.Field<Nullable<double>>("FinalPrice") != null ? x.Field<Nullable<double>>("FinalPrice") : 0),
                                TaxNote = x.Field<String>("TaxNote")
                            });

                            bulkOperation.Setup<Product>()
                                .ForCollection(productList) // requires IEnumerable to work with destination table
                                .WithTable("Product")
                                .AddAllColumns()
                                .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
                                .SetIdentityColumn(x => x.ProductId)
                                .MatchTargetOn(x => x.SessionNo)
                                .MatchTargetOn(x => x.LotNumber)
                                .MatchTargetOn(x => x.RegNumber);

                            bulkOperation.CommitTransaction(conn);

                            break;

                            // other unrelated case stuffs
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Error: DataTable is null or empty
                        ViewBag.Error = "No data present."
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "An error occurred when importing data. Message: " + e.Message;
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Success", "Notify");
    }
}
```

View (Import.cshtml)

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Data Import Example";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using Project.Models

@model FileModel

<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "File", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>File name:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileName)
    <br />
    <p>Worksheet name:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SheetName)
    <br />
    <p>SQL table name:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TableName)
    <br />
    <p>File to upload:</p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileToUpload, new { type = "file" })
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Import to Database" />
}
</div>
<div>@ViewBag.Error</div>
```

**Problem Statement**

The application imports data inside Excel worksheet into a `DataTable` which targeting Product table with bulk upsert procedure (update if existing data found, insert if no matching data present).

The Excel worksheet table structure is exactly same as database table and model class has, however the values are submitted by someone else thus I can't alter worksheet contents, and possibly `InitPrice` and `FinalPrice` column has empty value, which likely translated as `DBNull`. All other numeric values are treated as `double`.

When any data entry person uploaded his/her Excel worksheet through `Import` page with null value(s) exist on either `InitPrice` or `FinalPrice` column (of course it doesn't fill entire column with nulls), it returned same page with message:

> An error occurred when importing data. Message: Unable to cast object
>   of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Double'.

which exception pointed to `InitPrice` or `FinalPrice` assignment inside `Select` method.

However when zero values assigned substituting nulls, the import process completed successfully.

Questions to consider with:

1. How to assign default value (zero or null) as `Nullable<decimal>` on corresponding `IEnumerable` member(s) when either `InitPrice` or `FinalPrice` column contains `DBNull` value on source `DataTable`?
2. How can I use existing fields stored in `DataTable` as `IEnumerable` for bulk upsert without declaring every target column fields using `Select` method? If can't, which workarounds can be done?

I had looking for suggestions in [How to perform Update and Insert in SQL Server 2012 using SQL Bulk insert C# and ignore the duplicate values if already present in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389394/how-to-perform-update-and-insert-in-sql-server-2012-using-sql-bulk-insert-c-shar) & [Bulk Insert Sql Server millions of record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731179/bulk-insert-sql-server-millions-of-record), but those problem uses plain SqlBulkCopy instead of SqlBulkTools or bulk upsert with stored procedure.

Comment: So why not use SqlBulkCopy directly? It's quite straightforward.

Comment: I'm so confused as to what your question is...

Comment: I can't use `SqlBulkCopy` since it must update existing records if exists, using `ProductId` as identity column. The main problem is using `DataTable` numeric column field with `DBNull` inside as `Nullable<decimal>` in IEnumerable without cast exception, supposing all numeric values from Excel file are `double`.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Checking for DBNull

You are getting this error because of your use of [Field<T>(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field#System_Data_DataRowExtensions_Field__1_System_Data_DataRow_System_String_), which causes access to the column to be strongly-typed. This line of code

```
InitPrice = (decimal)(x.Field<Nullable<double>>("InitPrice") != null ? x.Field<Nullable<double>>("InitPrice") : 0),
```

fails before it even gets to do the null comparison, because Field<T>(String) is trying to cast DBNull to a Nullable<double>, which it can't do. To safely check for DBNull, use [Item[String]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_) instead, which returns an Object and, thus, does not have an issue with DBNull.

Example:

```
// convert DataTable into IEnumerable for bulk upsert
var productList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Product()
{
    SessionNo = x.Field<double>("SessionNo").ToString(),
    ProductName = x.Field<String>("ProductName"),
    Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
    LotNumber = x.Field<String>("LotNumber"),
    RegNumber = x.Field<String>("RegNumber"),

    InitPrice = (decimal)(!DBNull.Value.Equals(x["InitPrice"]) ? x.Field<Nullable<double>>("InitPrice") : 0),
    FinalPrice = (decimal)(!DBNull.Value.Equals(x["FinalPrice"]) ? x.Field<Nullable<double>>("FinalPrice") : 0),

    TaxNote = x.Field<String>("TaxNote")
});
```

## 2. Converting DataTable to an Enumerable SqlBulkTools Can Read Directly

SqlBulkTools checks for all public properties on the object you provide it and attempts to translate their names as column names in a SQL query. Changing a DataTable to an Enumerable gives you an IEnumerable<DataRow>, and on DataRow, the columns are not properties, but are accessed by string index or column index instead, so SqlBulkTools wouldn't be able to find them. You can use something like [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html) instead of a Select statement, but regardless, as long as the initial data is stored in a DataTable, you will have to convert it in some way before SqlBulkTools can read it.

## Avoiding DBNull Entirely

If you don't want to deal with DBNull at all, you would have to move away from using an OleDbDataAdapter and DataTable. If this is an option for you, I would recommend [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.3.3) (note that versions 5 and beyond require a license). You would have to access data using row and column numbers or cell range syntax, as opposed to column names, but when the cell has nothing in it, you will be given null instead of DBNull.