# custom Object collection to SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, performance, generics, sqldatareader

I am trying to avoid using large objects in my current project, 
while I wish to upload collections of data to populate an SQL Server Table

I am planning on SqlBulkCopy(alternative could also be Sproc with table value parameter but that's not the scope of my current question)

as the method accepts either a `DataTable` or `SqlDataReader`

I was wondering if I could do something like :

```
public struct tblCarOb
{
    public String Model;
    public Int32 Year;
}
```

as i prefer structs over class objects it could be a class to.

```
List<tblCarOb> tcoLst = new List<tblCarOb>(){ new tblCarObj(){ Model = "A", Year= 2010 }};
using (sqlConnection ...)
{
    use Reader to read form tcoLst or tblCarOb[]

}
```

so I could avoid using the more complex `DataTable`

question is could it be done somehow ?

**Update**

```
public struct tblCarOb
{
    public String Model;
    public Int32 Year;
}
```

- the idea is simple getting any object created as code above
- without using `EntityFrameWork`
- in my case I do not need to drop /create SQL Server Table
- in my case The C# table object I create has a corresponding table in SQL Server
- I prefer not to use reflection as I do with `DataTable`
- ** adding another class to implement it would be ok but not a whole DLL with 100K lines as the idea is to minimize the footprint.

the intention was to minimize overhead and performance hit.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it can be done. This is possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2258310/1048425 but not sure enough to close the question. Another example of a wrapper class that exposes IEnumarable as IDataReader can be found here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ObjectDataReader-8476dd72,

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this code

```
        using (IDataReader reader = tcoLst.GetDataReader())
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(....))
        using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //-->>>>>>>define this value
            bcp.DestinationTableName = "YourTableName";

            string createTableSql = string.Empty;

            createTableSql += string.Format("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.name =  {0}) DROP TABLE {0};", bcp.DestinationTableName);
            createTableSql += string.Format("CREATE TABLE dbo.{0};",bcp.DestinationTableName);

            for (int column = 0; column < reader.FieldCount; column++)
            {
                if (column > 0)
                {
                    createTableSql += ",";
                }

                createTableSql += "[" + reader.GetName(column) + "]" + " VARCHAR(MAX) NULL";
            }

            createTableSql += ");";

            using (SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand(createTableSql, conn))
            {
                createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
```

Comment: `GetDataReader()` ? list Extension I did not hear about   ?

Comment: I found something in google : http://www.csvreader.com/posts/GenericListDataReader.cs  found on http://www.csvreader.com/posts/generic_list_datareader.php

Comment: but I think it's using `EntityFramework` Objects and not my custom standard class object or struct object

Comment: I couldn't Implement your current code on any plain object List<T> does not recognize `GetDataReader()` how come you get your code to work  ?

Comment: @AghilasYakoub  can you please explain your answer