# SqlClient Bulk Insert Without DataTable in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm investigating porting our API's to .Net Core 1.0.

Unfortunately, `datatable` is not supported, and we use them to bulk insert data into SQL Server.

For example:

```
const string sqlText = @"
                INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name)
                SELECT ID, Name
                FROM @MyList n
                ";      
var dataTable = new DataTable("MyTable");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_tbsConnection))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    try
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, connection, transaction);
        var sqlFixture = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyList", dataTable);
        sqlFixture.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        sqlFixture.TypeName = "InsertList";
        var rowsAffected = await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

How can I easily change this to allow bulk insert, without using datatables?

Comment: What did you end up doing to address this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: Just migrate to .Net Core 2.0 - `Datatable` is supported there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatables have been added to .Net Core 2.0 - [Exploring DataTable and SqlDBAdapter in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2017/05/15/exploring-datatable-and-sqldbadapter-in-asp-net-core-2-0/)

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(SqlConnection conn, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    // just doing this cause dr.load fails
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerID");
    dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName");
    SqlDataReader dr = ExecuteReader(conn, cmdType, cmdText, cmdParms);
    // as of now dr.Load throws a big nasty exception saying its not supported. wip.
    // dt.Load(dr);
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1]);
    }
    return dt;
}

public static DataTable ExecuteDataTableSqlDA(SqlConnection conn, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code does not use `SqlBulkCopy` ("bulk insert") right now, so I'm not sure we're talking about the same things here; but anyway [it looks](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a59bf6473733827293030457c8a8b147f1e573af/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs#L1384) as if .NET Core does support the [`WriteToServer(DbDataReader)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906184(v=vs.110).aspx) (note link is for the full .NET framework, but should give you an idea) overloads. So you could use those instead, by wrapping your "data source" with a `DbDataReader`, i.e. have it implement it.

There are a couple of answers related to this on SO already. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2258448/21567) might be one of particular interest.

Comment: Does SQLBulkCopy have the same flexibility when adding a list of items to the database? For example we use `INSERT INTO using SELECT with OUTPUT INTO` etc.

Comment: As alternative to custom DbDataReader implementation it is possible to use [RecordSetReader](https://github.com/nreco/data/blob/master/src/NReco.Data/RecordSetReader.cs) from [NReco.Data](https://github.com/nreco/data) library (supports .NET Core).